# Change styling on parent:after by hovering child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

Lets say i have this list

```
<ul class="parent">
    ::before
    <li class="child"></li>
    <li class="anotherchild"></li>
    ::after
</ul>
```

Is it possible to change the style of the `parent::after` on `child:hover` with css, jquery or vanilla js?

```
.child:hover .parent:after{}
```

Does not seem to work

```
.parent:hover:after{}
```

works, but this is not what i hope to achieve.

After reading several posts, it seems tricky to alter the psuedo-element style in js, and i'm unsure if hovering child to alter parent is possible at all(?)

Comment: You can't change the parent element when hovering the child in pure css. only the other way around.

Comment: Here i want to change the parents :after psuedo-element when hovering child. Does it also apply for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with pure css but you can do it with javascript or jQuery.

Here is a demo of it done with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".child").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("childHovered");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("childHovered");
  })
})
```

If you want to change the `:after` psuedo element then you can add the psuedo effect to other class like the example below where i've changed the text color

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".child").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("childHovered");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("childHovered");
  })
})
```

```css
.parent.childHovered {
  color: blue;
}

.parent.childHovered::after {
  content:"";
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background-color:#000;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child">child</li>
  <li class="anotherchild">anotherchild</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect. Simple neat solution

Comment: @Thomas No problem, happy to help

Comment: Forgot to add: Im stuck with Jquery 1.11 for this, so I had to alter your code a bit and use $(document).on('mouseenter', '.child', function () {} instead.

Comment: @Thomas Yer, didn't know that but +1 for adding it to the comment so other might also get use of that information

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript Solution

---

#### Adding rules to the stylesheet

```js
const child = document.querySelector(".child");

child.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  const parent = child.parentElement;
  document.styleSheets[0].addRule('div.parent:after', 'content: "Hovering";');
})

child.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  const parent = child.parentElement;
  document.styleSheets[0].addRule('div.parent:after', 'content: "Not Hovering";');
})
```

```css
.parent::after {
  content: "Not Hovering";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="child">Child</button>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution using classes

```js
const child = document.querySelector(".child");

child.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  child.parentElement.classList.toggle("hovering");
  
})

child.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  child.parentElement.classList.toggle("hovering");
})
```

```css
.parent::after {
  content: "Not Hovering";
}

.parent.hovering::after {
  content: "Hovering";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="child">Child</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Thomas Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Did not get this to work for me. Seems like you added the same solution (second solution) to your answer after I accepted Carsten's answer.

Comment: Carsten's solution is in jQuery.

Comment: I asked if this is possible in CSS, jquery or vanilla JS in my question, so jquery is perfectly fine. Did you really downvote because I did not accept your answer?

Comment: @Thomas I didn't downvote buddy! Its good to have variety in the answers so that if someone in the future visits this post, he/she might get to see different possible solutions. And my first solution is entirely different from Carstens'.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee While I agree that your solution is totally different, one question comes to mind, why didn't you provide the html the op used? We should always aim to make the answers be as close to the questions as posible.

Comment: Ok then. All help is appreciated. A vanilla JS solution like you provided might come handy for those who can not use jquery.